# Replicating SUMIFS from Excel to Qlikview Script

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I have the below formula in Excel/VBA which I am trying to replicate in my Qlikview script but I am failing miserably.

```
Range("AP2").Value = "=SUMIFS(AJ:AJ,Q:Q,Q2,I:I,""CONSUMER"")"
```

- Column AJ contains a monetary amount.
- Column Q contains a "unique ID", there are duplicates but not always of these IDs based on a reference which doesn't need to be used in this specific formula.
- Column I contains the type of user for example "COMPANY", "CONSUMER", "COMMISSION".

The formula sums up the amounts in AJ only if there are more than one "unique ID" and "CONSUMER".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to you use a **set expression**.

It will look like this:

`SUM({<unique_ID = {'1234556'}, user_type = {'COMPANY', 'CONSUMER'}>} amount)`

'unique_ID', 'user type' and 'amount' are the field names
The fields 'unique_ID', 'user type' will be the filters and the 'amount' will be the field for the aggregation